# what's DSL in plain words?

Tags: terminology, dsl

I heard from someone that DSL is really powerful in some specific fields. So i want to find out if i can put it into my skill sets.

The first problem came out is What is DSL exactly? After doing some search, it seems Groovy supports DSL very well. Then i  go and read Groovy's documents and try it out by myself.

And i got the impression that DSL is just some kind of configuration files consisting of texts, XMLs and you use some tools like Groovy to parse it,  it magically become some methods or functions you can invoke. What happened?

I read something, but cannot get it straight. Any Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you read [this](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DomainSpecificLanguage.html)?  Martin Fowler is an authority on the subject and a great writer.  I doubt that anyone will improve on the first paragraph.  If you still don't get it, give it some time and re-read the article a few times.

I'd recommend looking into JetBrain's [MPS](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/)

A book might be overwhelming, but there's a [relatively new one available](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321712943).

> And i got the impression that DSL is just some kind of configuration
>   files consisting of texts, XMLs and you use some tools like Groovy to
>   parse it, it magically become some methods or functions you can
>   invoke. What happened?

I don't think your impression is entirely accurate.  I'd forget about Groovy and parsing and all the implementation details for now.  Focus on the problem that DSL is trying to solve.

A DSL designer tries to come up with a pseudo programming language that an expert, who is unfamilar with programming languages like Groovy or Java or C#, would recognize as a *simple* language describing they way *they* solve problems.

The DSL uses terms and concepts familiar to *any one* knowledgable about that domain.

The DSL shields users from the underlying implementation details so they can focus on how to attack their problems.

A DSL is written for the convenience of *business users*, not developers.

Keep that in mind and the rest is implementation.  Eye on the prize....

Comment: I am trying to get the big picture first and to figure out how a common DSL works.

Comment: I don't think you'll get a better big picture than the one Martin Fowler paints for you.

Comment: I just want to understand Martin Fowler's and of course, i cannot.

Comment: It doesn't get much simpler than that.  I doubt that anyone here will improve on what he has to say.  Perhaps you're being too impatient; read it a few times and mull it over.  Learning takes some time.

Comment: George, it might be helpful if you explained what part of Martin Fowler's explanation you didn't understand.

Answer (score 2):

A domain specific language (DSL) is a programing language that is not fully featured.  The point is that programing in a DSL can be easier than programing in a general purpose language, and be less prone to bugs.  The "domain" in "domain specific language" refers to the specific purpose the language will be used for.

For example, the language that a calculator uses with just + - * / and numbers could be called a domain specific language.  It has the advantage over a regular programing language in that programs will never segfault, crash, loop forever, etc.  Other examples of domains might be web development -- for example, Ur/Web is a DSL for building web applications.  SQL is a database domain specific language.  etc.

I don't know much about Groovy, but it seems that there are particular tools for using it to create DSLs.  Fundamentally, to create a DSL you need to specify a syntax, along with some sort of semantics.  How exactly Groovy does this I do not know.

Answer (score 2):

DSL is a language dedicated to a specific domain. For instance, the well-known CSS is a Domain Specific Language serving the look and formatting of a document.

By using Groovy you might create your own DSL focusing on any selected domain - e.g. accounting, telecommunications, banking etc. This means, that the language will use the common terminology of this area meeting the needs of this domain. This language will be easily understood by people of this domain that are not necessarily technical (e.g. accountants). In some times, it focuses on being used by non-programmers. Especially Groovy is a dynamic language with which you can enable end-users to add code scripts dynamically similarly to what Excel does with VB, through configuration files.

You should delve into Martin Fowler's publications if you are interested in this subject, anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I just ordered his book.

Comment: "DSL is a language dedicated to a specific domain" == tautology.

Comment: Although it's not necessarily connected with DSL, you might find some interesting concepts in "Domain Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software", a very interested book  by Eric Evans.